# Auto scrolling through multiple widgets on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using several widgets placed on a canvas to show progress through several tasks.  In order to do this I am placing them in a grid on a Canvas in a Frame.  Almost everything works but I need the scrollbar to default to the bottom of the window (frame).  I have tried to use vsb.set to force the scrollbar to a new position but it has no effect.  If I use the event handler to move the scrollbar I lose control of its movement.  I am a newbie and would appreciate some input.  See code below.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff", height=300, width=700)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        root.title("Issue with Scrolling through Widgets")
        self.populate()     

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        ###Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*int(event.delta/120),"units" )

    def populate(self):
        ###Put in some fake data###
        for row in range(20):                        
            Txt = Text(self.frame, bg="white", borderwidth=1, height=1, width=40)
            Txt.grid(row = row, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S)
            line = "this is the first column for row %s" %row
            Txt.insert(END, str(line))
            Txt = Text(self.frame, bg="white", borderwidth=1, height=1, width=40)
            Txt.grid(row = row, column = 1, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S)
            line = "this is the second column for row %s" %row
            Txt.insert(END, str(line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: By "default to the bottom of the window", are you saying you want the contents scrolled to the bottom, or do you mean you want the actual scrollbar to be in a different physical position?

Comment: I would like it to default to showing what was last sent to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would like to have the scrollbar move down as new data is put on the grid.  I found a solution that works but I'm not sure it's proper. I changed the onFrameConfigure function to the following.

```
def onFrameConfigure(self, event):  # Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
    global insertFlag
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
    if insertFlag == 1:
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(20, "units")
        insertFlag = 0
```

and then added to the bottom of the populate an if statement to set the global variable, as below.

```
def populate(self):
    global insertFlag
    for row in range(20):
        Txt = Text(self.frame, bg="white", borderwidth=1, height=1, width=40)
        Txt.grid(row = row, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        line = "this is the second column for row %s" %row
        Txt.insert(END, str(line))
        Txt.see(END)
    insertFlag = 1
```

What do you think, your input is appreciated.